# Input field, on focus, assign value, on blur keep value, on focus keep value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, focus, field

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a simple input field, if it has an empty value, on focus, I want to give it a value of 12345.

The issue is that once the value becomes 12345, and I put anything (e.g. 7890) after it, click ouside, click back inside, it removes the 7890.

http://jsfiddle.net/4VYpV/

How can I have the 7890 or anything after that act as the value so it does not get erased on blur and focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had focus function bind and the check for a blank val swapped.

Try this:

**EDIT:** Updated the code to remove the redundant each function based on @karim79's comments

```
$('.inputField').focus(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val("12345");
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4VYpV/1/

Comment: It's also worth noting, the `.each` is totally redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SveLU/)?

```
$('.inputField').each(function() {
  if($(this).val() == '')
    $(this).focus(function(){
      if($(this).val() == '')
      $(this).val("12345");
  });    
});
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph, both answers work, I chose Cybernate's since it uses the least amount of code, great answer regardless:)